# Redux issue with erroractions may not have an undefined "type" property

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am first time using redux with async call in API. I am facing a issue with this error " Actions may not have an undefined "type" property."

if any one know redux well please check this code. I also corrected the filenames below.

my code is mentioned below:

**actionTypes.js**

```
export const SET_LOGIN_STATE = "SET_LOGIN_STATE"
```

**actions.js**

```
import * as t from '../constants/actionTypes';

const setloginState = (logindata) => {

    return {
        type: t.SET_LOGIN_STATE,
        payload: logindata,
    }

}
```

**reducer.js**

```
import * as t from '../constants/actionTypes';


const initialState = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    userId: '',
    token: '',
    refreshToken: '',
    expiresOn: '',
    data: '',
  };

  
export const loginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case t.SET_LOGIN_STATE:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload, // this is what we expect to get back from API call and login page input
        isLoggedIn: true, // we set this as true on login
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**store.js**

```
    import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
    import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
    //import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly'; // this is for debugging with React-Native-Debugger, you may leave it out
    import { loginReducer } from '../reducers/reducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loginReducer: loginReducer,
});

export const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)
);
```

UI - app.js

```
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';
    import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
    import {login} from './actions/actions';
    
    function App() {
      const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    
      const _doLogin =  async data => {
          
    
            // axios post
            return (dispatch) => { 
            axios.post('/invoice/webapps/api/login', data, {
                headers: {
                   Accept: 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }})
              .then(function (response) {
                var responsedata=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                if(responsedata.data.login_status === "Done"){
    
            console.log("correct");
                  //  localStorage.setItem("authtoken", responsedata.data.api_token);
                  //dispatch(setLoginState('correct'));
                
                }
                else{ /// invalid login
    
            console.log("correct");
                
                }
              })
              .catch(function (error) {
                //Swal.fire("Error", error, "warning");
                console.log(error);
              });
    
        }
    
    }
    
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div>Login 
          <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(useDispatch(_doLogin))}>
            Enter your username : <input className="form-control h-auto form-control-solid py-4 px-8" type="text" 
                                        placeholder="Email"  autoComplete="off" {...register("email", {
                                            required: true, 
                                            pattern: {
                                               value: /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                                               message: 'Please enter a valid email',
                                           }, })}/>
            Enter your password :   <input className="form-control h-auto form-control-solid py-4 px-8" type="password"
                                         placeholder="Password" autoComplete="off" 
                                         {...register("password", {
                                             required: true, 
                                             })} />
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: The names of your files look suspicious. What is the name of the file containing the actual type `SET_LOGIN_STATE`? You have the name `Actiontype.js` above it but then it seems you are importing the type from `../constants/actionTypes`

Comment: check it again. it was typos. i corrected the filename.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not the way `useDispatch` is used. On the body of your component you need to call it like so:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
```

and then use it inside your `_doLogin`

Binding your submitHandler should be done like this: `onSubmit={handleSubmit(_doLogin)}`

The full code would be:

```js
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {setLoginState} from './actions/actions';
    
function App() {
  const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
    
  const _doLogin =  async data => {
    //axios post
    return axios.post('/invoice/webapps/api/login', data, {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }}).then(function (response) {
        var responsedata=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
        if(responsedata.data.login_status === "Done"){
         console.log("correct");
         //localStorage.setItem("authtoken", responsedata.data.api_token);
         dispatch(setLoginState('correct'));
       } else {
        // invalid login
       }
      }).catch(function (error) {
                //Swal.fire("Error", error, "warning");
                console.log(error);
     });    
    }
    
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div>Login 
          <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(_doLogin)}>
            Enter your username : <input className="form-control h-auto form-control-solid py-4 px-8" type="text" 
                                        placeholder="Email"  autoComplete="off" {...register("email", {
                                            required: true, 
                                            pattern: {
                                               value: /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
                                               message: 'Please enter a valid email',
                                           }, })}/>
            Enter your password :   <input className="form-control h-auto form-control-solid py-4 px-8" type="password"
                                         placeholder="Password" autoComplete="off" 
                                         {...register("password", {
                                             required: true, 
                                             })} />
            <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

#### Edit 1

Make sure you export your action from `actions.js` and name it properly set**L**oginState

Comment: i am thinking dispatch should be a block of axios. But i will check it and let you know here.

Comment: Same error "Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. You may have misspelled an action type string constant."

Comment: have you tried to replace all occurences of `t.SET_LOGIN_STATE` with the string `'SET_LOGIN_STATE'`? If this fixes your issue then you have some mispelled import. I don't have your full directory structure to validate your imports.

Comment: let me mention here my directory structure

1 actions/actions.js
2. constants/actionTypes.js
3. reducers/reducer.js
4. store/store.js

outer one is app.js, index.js

code is all same mention above. if you can play with your login api.

Comment: @wontone_boys check my edit, it seems you mispelled setLoginState and as far as i see you don't export it either.

Comment: while working in the morning, i also seen that error and after exporting that also it giving me same error.

Comment: Have you also fixed the naming and import in your App component?
`import {setLoginState} from './actions/actions';` and
`export const setLoginState = (logindata) => ...`